# App engine blobstore data quota not reset

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, quota

My app has reached the 5gb quota in blobstore storage for free apps. I've deleted all the blobstore data but still have an error when try creating the new blobs.

After the daily quota has been reset the quota details page still shows that 100% of the quota is used and rate is limited.

What should I do to enable the blobstore usage for the app again other than enable billing?

Comment: Do you see anything in the *Blob Viewer* from your Application's dashboard?

Comment: No, I've deleted everything via Blob Viewer

Comment: After another day the quota has restored, so the problem has gone. Thanks everybody.